# Is Shakespeare really the source of our modern meaning for odd?

Tags: etymology, shakespeare

In a [recent article](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/apr/04/why-all-love-numbers-mathematics), the Guardian states that

> Shakespeare is also responsible for the modern meaning of "odd".

What is the evidence for this? The [textual evidence alone](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Glossary.aspx?Ref=odd%20a&ID=12046) is thin and unconvincing.

Is Shakespeare really the source of our modern meaning for odd as unexpected, strange, or unusual?

Comment: The OED has citations for this meaning from ca 1500, almost a century before Shakespeare wrote his plays. *"How ferre odde those persones are from the nature of this prince."* (1542)

Comment: @PeterShor that should be an answer! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it turns on blurring the distinction between ***first recorded use*** (of a word or sense which may well have been around for some time) and ***innovative coinage*** (of a usage which we assume never previously existed at all).

Comment: @PeterShor The [*Middle English Dictionary*](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=127601504&egdisplay=open&egs=127615871) has even earlier citations, one from 1450, and one from Gower 1393 which makes the transition from the numeric to the figurative significance clear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But as Peter Shor points out,Shakespeare's use of the word is neither of these. The sense was already established and documented.

Comment: @StoneyB: Peter's citation is for OED's definition II 6a *a. Not even, aligned, or accordant; uneven, unequal, discrepant, diverse, different.* But OP's sense is more properly covered by their definition II 9a *Of persons, their actions, etc.: strange in behaviour or appearance; peculiar; eccentric; unexpected.* For which the first citation is 1577 - closely followed by Shakespeare using it in 1598 (and OP's link shows a usage in *The Taming of the Shrew*, c1590-1592). However you look at it, the Guardian's claim doesn't stand scrutiny.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes; and that is, in fact, the answer OP is looking for. It's a legitimate question—post your answer!

Comment: @StoneyB: I think Peter's comment *and* yours and mine all point in the same general direction - the question is predicated on an unfounded assertion. But if OP had simply asked *How and when did "odd" acquire the sense of "peculiar"?* it would presumably have been closed as General Reference anyway. Apart from the spurious suggestion that Shakespeare "coined" the usage, it's all perfectly well covered by [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=odd).

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, etymonline says only '1580s', which does not exclude Shakespeare. The date of *TS* is very controversial, many scholars holding that it derives from an *Ur-Shrew* of the 1580s. [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/58/mode/2up), under 6.b. gives a citation to *LLL* which it dates to 1588. The question cannot be answered without access to a source providing a citation demonstrably earlier than any of Shakespeare's uses of the word in this sense.

Comment: I'm *so* glad I'm not in the Humanities.

Comment: @StoneyB, raxacoricofallapatorius: It just seems to me the shift/extension(s) in meaning are both small and gradual - and one can easily imagine even smaller "incremental changes" than the already fine distinctions implied by some of OED's separate "same but different" definitions. It also seems clear to me that although Shakespeare didn't exactly "coin" anything here, it's understandable if that Guardian columnist thinks he was "pivotal" in introducing the usage to a wider audience. But all I can see here is discussion, not "answers".

Comment: @StoneyB If the sense (meant by the Guardian) is as old as the sun, would that count as "modern"? The Guardian was *not* referring to the older stuff.

Comment: @Kris The point at issue is when *odd* was first used in  the modern sense of "peculiar", not when it was first used in that sense so in Modern English. Mr. Belios claims (probably relying on *OED 1*) that the first use in that sense was in *LLL*. Peter Shor and FumbleFingers have given earlier uses in EModE and I have given earlier uses in ME.

Comment: @StoneyB "when odd was first used in the modern sense of "peculiar", not when it was first used in that sense" -- ??

Comment: @Kris Argh - bad editing ... ignore the 'so'. "Not when it was first used in that sense **in Modern English**."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *odd* had this meaning much earlier. The first citation the OED gives for it is around 1500. The 1542 citation:

> "How ferre odde those persones are from the nature of this prince."

quite clearly has this meaning.

Furthermore, *Troilus and Cressida* has the following dialogue, where Shakespeare is punning on the two different meanings of *odd*:

> Menelaus. I'll give you boot, I'll give you three for one.
>   Cressida. You're an odd man; give even or give none.
>   Menelaus. An odd man, lady! every man is odd.
>   Cressida. No, Paris is not; for you know 'tis true,
>   That you are odd, and he is even with you.

If he had just invented one of the meanings, these puns wouldn't be funny.

Comment: Is 1500 "modern"? I don't know really.

Answer (score 1):

> Shakespeare is also responsible for the modern meaning of "odd".

Obviously, you have read the sentence at variance from what the author meant.

If the bard were the first to use the word in that sense, then why *also*? Moreover, what is the awkward "responsible" doing there when one would expect a direct attribution?

The author seems to imply that had Shakespeare not described the Spaniard Don Adriano de Armado as "too picked, too spruce, too affected, **too odd,** as it were" in *Love's Labour's Lost,* the Modern sense of the word would not have caught on. "Originally, the word only had a numerical sense. It was used in phrases such as 'odd man out', the unpaired member of a group of three."

Expressions and their meanings just get wider acceptance when used in widely-read and respected writings.